# I am running a eloquent query, but i am stuck in a position

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am new in Laravel.
***$year*** 'all' is every possible year

```
all, 2022, 2021, 2020, 2019
```

if i pass params any of them except **all** its working fine.
but when i pass **all**  as condition. i have no idea what to do?
Please help me.

```
public function findResultServiceFeeDubai($address, $type, $year, $norows){
     
        $result = DB::table('service-charges')
        ->select('address', 'year', 'type', 'total_charge_sqft')
        ->orWhere('address', 'LIKE', "%".$address."%")
        ->where('type', $type)
        ->where('year', $year)
        ->limit($norows)
        ->get();
        $response = $result;
        return response()->json($response, 200);

    }
```

```
Route::get('/findResultServiceFeeDubai/{name}/{type}/{year}/{norows}',[UserController::class,'findResultServiceFeeDubai'])->name('findResultServiceFeeDubai');
```

Comment: what are these `**` in your code? please do not decorate code that way. Add valid code comments etc, but do not add garbage to the code that makes things unclear

Comment: Welcome to SO ... does 'all' mean all possible years? or a set of years?

Comment: I removed ** i thought it will help to understand more.

Comment: @lagbox yes 'all' is every possible years

Comment: if `$year === 'all'` then don't add the where condition for year

Comment: thanks, but same situation also in type. so i want exact and best answer. please suggest

Comment: its the same thing then, if it is 'all' then don't add the condition for that field

Comment: @lagbox then it means there are 2 times if condition with the same code. without where

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling methods on a Query Builder. It is an object so you can assign it to a variable and make calls to it as needed to build your query. The `get` call is what is actually executing the query and returning a result. If you want to conditionally add query conditions to that query you can just use `if` statements (if you prefer to not use the functional approach):

```
$query = DB::table('service-charges')
    ->select('address', 'year', 'type', 'total_charge_sqft')
    ->where('address', 'LIKE', '%'. $address .'%')
    ->limit($norows);

if ($year !== 'all') {
    $query->where('year', $year);
}

if ($type !== 'all') {
    $query->where('type', $type);
}

$result = $query->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i needed. Everything works.